# Number (0-9) Keyboard on Mobile for Numeric Fields

Tags: html, mobile, input, keyboard, attributes

I’m trying to find the right code that will bring up the non-telephone, 0-9 keyboard on mobile for numeric fields such as ZIP code, DOB, Social Security #, etc. I’ve read some articles suggesting that the following code throws a thousands separator into a numeric field:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0=9]*”>
```

I don’t get the thousands separator when I test this code. These articles are from a few years ago, so I’m not sure if this is still an issue.

http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/cracking_the_code_for_a_numeric_keyboard
http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/better-numerical-inputs-for-mobile-forms/

Is the thousands separator issue still a problem? And in general, what do people use to pull up a non-telephone, 0-9 keyboard for number-based fields?